# kNN prediction different from distance value prediction

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have an issue with sklearn, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I want to classify website in 3 categories : 'financial', 'IT', 'health care'

I have several metrics for each website (basically a list of keywords), and I end up using a knn classifier :

```
# fit the classifier
 >>> y = array(['financial_services', 'health_care', 'information_technology'], dtype=object)
 >>> X.shape = (3L, 571L)
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X, y)

# predict the result for some website (predict is a matrix with my features)
print(neigh.predict(predict))
 >>> ['financial_services'] # predict the first category

print(neigh.kneighbors(predict)) # get the "distances" to each category
 >>> (array([[ 2323819.25162006,  2323841.23289028,  2323852.69883011]]), array([[2, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)) # we can see that this website is closer to the category #2, which is IT
```

I tried to predict the category of some other website, but I always end up with the same prediction using `neigh.predict`, e.g 'Financial services', while I get different value using the distance (with `neigh.predict`).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices array returned from `kneighbours` as per the `sklearn` documentation gives you the "*Indices of the nearest points in the population matrix*" not the class labels. The distances are sorted from closest to farthest and the indices tell you which distance corresponds to which instance in the training set. So `[[ 2323819.25162006,  2323841.23289028,  2323852.69883011]], [[2, 0, 1]]` tells you that the 3rd (index 2) instance is the closest with a distance of `2323819.25162006`. This can be a little confusing as you have exactly 3 points in the training data and `k=3`. The thing to keep in mind here is that the indices refer to indices *in your original training samples array* not to distances array returned from the same function.

I think your main problem however is that the population matrix contains exactly 3 examples for 3 classes (1 per class). When you set `kneighbours=3` what do you think the classifier is trying to do? Find the 3 nearest neighbours of a test point, but there are only three examples and they all have a different class.

The user guide has this to say

> Classification is computed from a simple majority vote of the nearest neighbors of each point

In your case the nearest 3 points. Again there are only three points and they all have a different class so the majority vote can never function correctly.

Comment: I understood that the 2nd array ("[[2, 0, 1]]") returned by `kneighbours was the "Indices of the nearest points in the population matrix." (so the doc says). So I thought the first number of this array (in this case 2) was corresponding to the first number in the distance array, which would mean the predicted point is closer to the point number 2 ?

Comment: no I think the first number in the distance array is the distance to the first element in the population matrix, I'm not exactly sure of that though. The main problem however is that there are only three neighbours each with a different class so the majority can not function regardless of the distances

Comment: I thought the distance was taken into account to "weight" the vote. I will dig  a bit more in the doc.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I had the wrong understanding of the kNN. So my prediction is submitted to a majority vote between the 3 nearest training point : as each of them is in a different class, the first one is always winning. That being said, the `kneighbors` is indeed giving the distance between my point to predict and the training points, which is really what I'm after. If you could correct your answer, I will gladly give you the points to thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the implementation decides which class wins, is it always the first one or a random one. I'm not sure what part you want me to change in my answer? I don't see any factual error. Do you mean the `population matrix`

Comment: No error, just to clarify the part with the distance : the `kneighbour` is in fact evaluating the distance and sort them from smallest to largest, and gives the associated indexes along (the second matrix). In my exemple, the prediction is class n°0 (because of the 3 classes, 3k), but the closest is actually the n°2, e.g my 3rd category

Comment: ah, I see - that was actually a factual error. See edited answer